# Making this code more efficient by adding a loop into it

Tags: database, loops, matlab

```
returns1 = ri_f_inyear(1:12, 1);
cumulativeReturns1 = (cumprod(1+ returns1 / 100)-1)*100;

returns2 = ri_f_inyear(1:12, 2);
cumulativeReturns2 = (cumprod(1+ returns2 / 100)-1)*100;

returns3 = ri_f_inyear(1:12, 3);
cumulativeReturns3 = (cumprod(1+ returns3 / 100)-1)*100;

returns4 = ri_f_inyear(1:12, 4);
cumulativeReturns4 = (cumprod(1+ returns4 / 100)-1)*100;

returns5 = ri_f_inyear(1:12, 5);
cumulativeReturns5 = (cumprod(1+ returns5 / 100)-1)*100;

returns_total = [cumulativeReturns1 cumulativeReturns2 cumulativeReturns3 cumulativeReturns4 cumulativeReturns5 ]
```

I was struggling to build a loop, therefore, I did it manually for 5 columns( I have 500 in total) and tried to work from here, I am still struggling though. Could someone help me please to optimise this code. Sadly the code ChatGPT gives me doesn't work either.

I tried to take the width of my table and take that as a parameter on the loop but it didn't work

Comment: what does `ri_f_inyear` returns? i couldn't find it in matlab stock functions

Comment: So you are showing us how you solved it for 5 columns by doing it manually but you are not showing us your approach to do it with a for loop. If you want to learn from your mistakes you should add this information. Please read [ask] and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also this can help you a lot [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

So you have repeats of

```
returns = ri_f_inyear(1:12, 1); 
cumulativeReturns = (cumprod(1+ returns / 100)-1)*100;
```

Where I've removed the number suffix from your variable names.

Then you combine all of these variables with

```
returns_total = [cumulativeReturns1 cumulativeReturns2 ...  cumulativeReturnsN ]
```

The first part can be left as-is and put in a loop. First we should define the output array, I'm going to assume that `ri_f_inyear(1:12, 1);` returns a 12*1 column vector, so the number of rows of your output is 12. Then instead of merging multiple variables at the end, assign directly into a column of the output matrix.

```
Nr = 12; % Number of rows
Nc = 5;  % Number of columns
returns_total = NaN( Nr, Nc ); % Initialise output array to all NaN
% Loop over the columns
for c = 1:Nc
    returns = ri_f_inyear(1:12, c); % Calculate this column's ri_f_inyear
    cumulativeReturns = (cumprod(1+ returns / 100)-1)*100; % calc cumulative
    % Assign to column of the output
    returns_total(:,c) = cumulativeReturns;
end
```